# Check if discrete signal is periodic (or close to), given discrete event times

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing, discrete-mathematics

So I have a list of times Z (see below) when a particular event happens. How can I see how close to periodic is this signal?
I guess, I can find the pairwise time differences between serial events and see if it's an approximately steady quantity, but is there a pythonic way to do this?

```
Z = [7.72, 10.9, 13.9, 16.69, 19.5, 22.31, 25.0, 27.69...]
```

Comment: You could do [Fourier analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis); Numpy has [various Fourier tools](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html), but you'll need to learn a bit of theory to use them effectively.

Comment: I recommend taking some basic statistics of the set. Depending on your needs, something like the variance of the successive differences may be the only number you need to calculate. If it is below some threshold, then your samples are pretty evenly spaced, and occasional outliers won't get the whole set declared nonperiodic. I would write up an answer with a few good stats-based methods, but I don't speak Python.

Comment: Ok, indeed the variance seems to be a good measure. Thank you. If you have other ideas feel free to share (even though I already have more than enough for a satisfying answer).  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question seems to be more about the algorithm for analyzing the signal, but to get the differences between successive pairs in Python you can use this code:

```
>>> Z = [7.72, 10.9, 13.9, 16.69, 19.5, 22.31, 25.0, 27.69]
>>> diffs = [a-b for a, b in zip(Z, Z[1:])]
>>> diffs
[-3.1800000000000006, -3.0, -2.790000000000001, -2.8099999999999987, -2.8099999999999987, -2.6900000000000013, -2.6900000000000013]
```

Using this you could define a function to compare the differences to a given value and tolerance:

```
def is_periodic(samples, value, tolerance=0):
    diffs = [a-b for a, b in zip(samples, samples[1:])]
    return all(d-tolerance <= value <= d+tolerance for d in diffs)

>>> is_periodic(Z, -3, 1)
True
>>> is_periodic(Z, -3, 0.5)
True
>>> is_periodic(Z, -3, 0.25)
False
```

Comment: The one change I would add is using the mean or median difference to determine the rate, since the OP didn't mention specify that the period is known.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Katie 's comment in terms of generality. @mhawke thank you for the answer. (According to Katie if I understood correctly, we remove the 'value' argument from the function; then replace the other 'value' with numpy.mean(diffs) in the return part)

Comment: There seems to be a function from numpy called "diff" that does exactly this job :)

Answer (score 1):

simplest I can think of is:-

```
>>> Z = [7.72, 10.9, 13.9, 16.69, 19.5, 22.31, 25.0, 27.69]
>>> iterate_till = len(Z)-1
>>> [(Z[i+1] - val) for i, val in enumerate(Z) if i<iterate_till]
[3.1800000000000006, 3.0, 2.7900000000000009, 2.8099999999999987, 2.8099999999999987, 2.6900000000000013, 2.6900000000000013]
```